# Java: workaround for no 'abstract static'

Tags: java, static, abstract

I am writing an app about Twisty Puzzles: the Rubik Cube, Pyraminx, Skewb and the like.
I have an abstract class 'TwistyPuzzle' and derived classes: TwistyCube, TwistyPyraminx, etc.
I have a dialog which provides basic information about each puzzle: it's name, its inventor, year of invention, basic description how the puzzle works.

This information about each puzzle is - IMHO - best kept inside each of the 'implementation' classes TwistyCube, TwistyPyraminx, etc. Static methods force themselves:

```
class TwistyCube extends TwistyPuzzle

static String getName()
  {
  return "Rubik Cube";
  }
```

but there seems to be no way to have the Dialog, which needs to display this information, query the classes - because there's no concept of an 'abstract static' method in Java.

So what are my options? What is the standard workaround for the lack of 'abstract static' in Java?

Comment: A method like that should be non-static because you'll always call it on an instance.

Comment: Of course not - the name of all instances of 'TwistyRubik' is the same. It clearly belongs to the class, not its instances.

Comment: What about creating a class annotations like @GameName?

Comment: Sure but only instance classes can be overridden and that's what you want to achieve, i.e. make implementations provide that info. If the instance method returns a literal it's still the same for every instance of that class. In fact an instance method internally very much looks like a static method with an implicit parameter that resembles `this`.

Comment: This is a workaround, thanks Thomas. 
How about a separate enum - one value per one type of a TwistyPuzzle - that would provide such info?

Comment: The fact that the name is the same for all instances of the puzzle is an implementation detail. You'd still query it from the instance. You can make the method return a constant (`public static final`) String.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, you cannot declare an `abstract static` method (or field).

This is not just syntax.  The fundamental reason is that Java `static` members are not inherited.  And that means that `static` members cannot normally be used polymorphically.  When you call a `static` method or access a `static` field, the decision of *which* classes member is called / used is determined at compile time, based solely on compile time type considerations.

So ... basically ... what you are trying to do cannot be done.

But there is a solution.  If you want to use `abstract` on a method, declare it as an instance method.  Whether you are doing this so that you can use the method polymorphically ... or for other reasons.

You argued against this by saying:

> A method like that should be non-static because you'll always call it on an instance. – Thomas 2 hours ago

> Of course not - the name of all instances of 'TwistyRubik' is the same. It clearly belongs to the class, not its instances. – Ralf Kleberhoff 1 hour ago

But I think you are missing the point.  Methods don't "belong" to instances.  Methods belongs to classes.  Even non-static methods.  We call non-static methods "instance" methods because they *typically* operate on the state of a specific instance.  But they don't need to.  And instance method can return information about the class it belongs to.

Here's how I would write your example:

```
public abstract class TwistyPuzzle {
    public abstract String getName();
    ...
}
    
public class TwistyCube extends TwistyPuzzle
    public String getName();
        return "Rubik Cube";
    }
    ...
}
```

So lets analyze this:

- Q: Does it have the desired *behavior*?  
  A: Yes.  Every `TwistyCube` instance will return `"Rubik Cube"`.
- Q: Is there any space overhead of making this a non-static method?  
  A: No.  Method code is shared, and since Java doesn't treat methods as updatable properties of an instance, there is no per-object storage overhead.
- Q: Is there an performance overhead in making this a non-static method?  
  A: In most cases No.  And if there is an overhead, then it is minimal.
- Q: Are there advantages over a `static` method?  
  A: Yes.  The `getName()` can be used polymorphically with *runtime* method dispatching.

So what is the *actual* problem here?  What does "belong" mean?

Frankly, I think it is just about the way that you have conceptualized instance methods.  The fact that you called a method on an instance doesn't mean that it needs to return information specific to that instance.

Think of Java as a tool.  Use it the way it was designed to be used.  If you want `abstract` (e.g. polymorphic) methods that deliver information about the current Java class, then *this* is the *standard* way to do it.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> How about a separate enum - one value per one type of a `TwistyPuzzle` - that would provide such info?

I guess that would work.  But now you have the problem of getting the correct `enum` value that relates to a specific `TwistyPuzzle` instance (or class) that you are enquiring about.  And you have a readability / maintainability issue with information pertaining to each `TwistyPuzzle` class living in a separate class; i.e. the `enum`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for such an in-depth answer. Maybe indeed the meat of the problem here is the fact that I always 'felt' that methods whose output does not depend on values of any instance variables should be static. Especially such simple methods which essentially return a constant, a per-class constant.

Comment: Enum - yes, I agree, making the method non-static is a better solution. Somehow this non-static approach leaves a bitter taste in my mouth though... Such methods SHOULD be static!

Comment: The flip-side is that from an OOPL purist perspective, `static` is an ugly wart on the Java language, and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.  In other words, this method SHOULD NOT be `static`.  The pragmatic answer is in between; see above.  Use Java as it was designed to be used.  They designed Java with limited support for "class level" members; i.e. no inheritance of them, etc.  Go with the flow, and use a mouthwash if the bitter taste offends you :-).

Comment: I don't agree. I mean, here in this specific example - I do agree, but in general I don't.  Pragmatic (and OOP!) programming is all about clear separation of data - objects & methods have access only to stuff they have to have access to, and nothing else. Which among other things means that if a method returns a constant, and therefore does not need to know the states of member variables of an instance of an object, then it should not have access to them at all, i.e. it should be static.

Comment: Well you need to talk to the Java designers about it.   And the people who invented  OO design.  There is literally nothing >>we<< can do to solve this problem for you.

Comment: Besides: making it non-static carries additional risk. Suddenly, in order to be able to call the method, I need to have an instance of the object around. In my specific example I always do (the button which returns info about a particular type of a TwistyObject only appears once the user choses some specific object in a separate dialog and therefore creates an instance of it) but in general there are cases where we might want to display such a dialog while no instance of such object has been created yet. The object might be huge; creating one just to return a constant? Hmm...

Comment: See my last comment.  :-|

Comment: Actually thinking about it some more - the 'non-static' approach looks worse and worse. My users can change the type of the TwistyObject at any time. Theoretically it should be very hard to fire up the 'Info' dialog and click on another button fast enough to switch the type of the object while the dialog is still being displayed, but from my experience if 10000 users use your app, 3 will somehow manage to do it, and we'll have three crashes, unless I do some synchronization here - add a flag which would make switching the type of an object impossible while the Info Dialog is being displayed..

Comment: So more complicated synchronization code, or occasional crashes because the instance of an object ceased to exist for a brief while. All to return a constant. God! I demand abstract static. Maybe the simplest thing to do would be to keep the methods static and have the Dialog cell them by reflection. Horrific, I know, but simpler. And I don't have to worry if the underlying instance of the TwistyObject still exists at the moment.

Comment: You realize that comments on StackOverflow are ephemeral and are liable to get deleted?  If you feel these comments are saying something important, you ought to capture them as (say) a self-answer to your question.  But bear in mind that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion site ...